# Parameter Estimation of any model

Tags: parameter-estimation

I am new to time series modelling.I cant get my head around parameter estimation and its methods. My question consists of 3 parts :

1st : Lets say i have a model like Garch or Heston model or a SVJD model having multiple terms and multiple iid random variables.How do i estimate the parameters with simple methods like mle or OLS (or its not possible) possibly in R using inbuilt functions for mle(i can do for estimating Arima).

2nd :  Is there a general approach i can use to estimate the parameters of any complex model without relying on any external library.

3rd : How does Kalman filters , Monte-carlo simulation, martingale measures can estimate parameters .(It would be very helpful if you could cite a book or a tutorial).

(Do i need to know all the estimation methods or a simple few would do for  testing mid-frequency strategies).

(I have read the source code of custom libraries in R and i could not understand anything (implementation) beyond Arima.)

Comment: Perhaps this could answer some of your questions: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484572/one-factor-mean-reverting-model-parameter-estimation-with-kalman-filter-linalg/484624#484624